# Calling Functions from Base contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I have a contract inheritance in my design and i want to call via web3 a method from the base contract. the oriblem is that i can't know how to do that :

if i do like this :

```
   contract B {
        uint Bstate;
        function methodX (){
        Bstate =1;
        }
    }
```

then

```
import "B.sol"; // because B is in an other file
contract A is B {

}
```

do i need to manually deploy `contract B` after deploying `contract A` and use its abi to call `methodX` or i can call it directly from the abi of `contract A`?

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance allows us to define a base contract, from which other contracts can use. This allows you to reuse base contracts in future contracts without having to rewrite code.

When contract A inherits from contract B, only contract A is actually deployed to the blockchain. All code from contract B is copied into contract A.